# O que é java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, array, exceção

O que causa essa exceção? Como se prevenir dessa exceção? Como corrigir ela?

Exemplo:

Tenho uma ArrayList onde guardo vários filmes em uma tabela (Jtable) onde faço a remoção dos filmes para não locar eles e tenho um método para remover um filme do Arraylist, ou seja, da tabela. Quando removo um filme sobrando um filme na tabela não ocorre essa exceção, mas quando removo um filme sem ter nenhum filme na tabela ocorre essa exceção.

Metodo para remover os filmes:

```
private void removeFilmeNaLista(){
        for (Iterator<Filme> it = listaFilmes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

            Filme i = it.next();

                 // aqui eu removo
                listaFilmes.remove(i);
                System.out.println("remove:" +(i));
                refazTabela();

        }
    }
```

Erro:

```
remove:model.Filme@16e0921
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at view.VideoLocacao.removeFilmeNaLista(VideoLocacao.java:495)
    at view.VideoLocacao.btnExcluirTbl2ActionPerformed(VideoLocacao.java:392)
```

O erro aparece a partir dessa linha 495 onde que esta ´Filme i = it.next();´.

Comment: Você está acessando o array ao mesmo tempo que está removendo itens??

Comment: @diegofm Sim, por que posso remover os filmes nessa array.

Comment: A resposta é exatamente o que comentei, você está iterando todo um array ao mesmo tempo em que remove itens. Veja [aqui](http://blog.caelum.com.br/concurrentmodificationexception-e-os-fail-fast-iterators/) uma explicação exata do seu problema e sua possivel solução.

Comment: @diegofm Entendi. O que posso fazer para corrigi essa exceção?

Comment: Veja no link  se a solução atende(não tenho como testar agora).

Comment: @diegofm Na possivel duplicata, o que gera a exceção, são elementos que estão a mais e na minha pergunta, são elementos que estão a menos.

Comment: Igor, você está dizendo que  substituír `listaFilmes.remove(i)` por `it.remove()` no seu código não resolve o problema? No segundo caso a remoção é "segura".

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Já consegui resolver a exceção apagando uma parte do código...Vou responder minha própria pergunta para ajudar os demais pessoas que não conseguiram resolver. :)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Como faço para responder minha própria pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver essa excecao apagando todo o laço For e `Filme i = it.next();`.

```
private void removeFilmeNaLista() {

            listaFilmes.remove(filme);

            refazTabela();
    }
```